# Wiring multiple single pole switch and light fixture in chain

Tags: electrical, wiring

[image]

Hello everyone,

I have posted a picture. I am thinking have power/current coming directly into a light fixture. then power jumping from one light fixture to another light fixture. there are two lights in a different location which are controlled by their on single pole switch showing in the picture. there could be more lights in each location/room.

Room/Location A- 4 recessed light controlled by a single switch
Room/Location  B- 4 recessed light controlled by a single switch

The issue I am seeing is :
Box filling violation as If I add more light-fixture to each location. then at each location we would have one such recessed light which would have total 4 wires(3-14/2 and 1-14/3) which might difficult to fit them all in light fixture box .

Is jumping from box to box is better than this ? I meant power will come to switch first then run wire from there its light fixture and another switch box.

Please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Thanks

Comment: Is adding extra boxes in the ceiling to house the cable junctions an option?

Comment: Yes, I can add but how/what/where its going to help ? Thank

Comment: They are cables not wires.  A cable is severql wires inside a sheath.  Number of cables isn't a factor in box fill, number of wires is.

Comment: A switch loop bringing neutral to the switch box. That's a good thing!

Comment: @FreeMan, Oh I didn't know this type of wiring called 'Switch loop' is this legal and can it pass inspection ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See where I said "good thing"? That's a good thing. AIUI, they're generally frowned upon these days because many switches require a neutral, and, traditionally a switch-loop was wired with a /2 cable that doesn't provide a neutral at the switch - your wiring does, so that's good. I'll leave it to one of the electricians like TPE or Harper to note whether this is actually code compliant with NEC 2017 or 2020...

Comment: What make and model are your recessed cans, for that matter?

Comment: Global electric 4 inch ultra thin ( can less) . I think this way will not work for me because I see the junction  box that comes with led ultra thin light doesn’t have much space. I am planning to wire switch to switch. Thanks